# Insert the extent of a geometry

Tags: postgis

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS features
(
    features_id integer NOT NULL,
    bbox character varying 200,
    geom geometry NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT features_pkey PRIMARY KEY (features_id)
);
```

I neet to insert a geom and its correspondent extent in this table so I tried this:

```
insert into features (features_id, bbox, geom) VALUES 
(default, 
ST_AsGeoJSON( ST_Extent(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-43.3568056,-22.9115278],[-43.3568056,-22.9118056],[-43.3565278,-22.9118056],[-43.3565278,-22.9115278],[-43.3568056,-22.9115278]]]}'))), 
ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(' {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-43.3568056,-22.9115278],[-43.3568056,-22.9118056],[-43.3565278,-22.9118056],[-43.3565278,-22.9115278],[-43.3568056,-22.9115278]]]} ') )
```

but seems I can't have ST_AsGeoJSON and ST_Extent inside an INSERT:

> ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in VALUES

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ST_Envelope`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Envelope.html) instead of `ST_Extent`, as the latter is an aggregate function